# jquery on toggle only change the surrounding divs class

Tags: jquery

when I click the link **hide information** link it shows **Show information** but it also changes the text on all the other boxes on the page, also when I click **hide information** it toggles the class **test** on the div class="revealBox" but it does it on all of the boxes, I would like to just keep it to the relevant box.

I know it will be something to do with $(this) I just don't know how to implement it.

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
var showText='Hide Information';
var hideText='Show Information';
var is_visible = false;
$('.collapseLink').append('<span class="dottedBot">'+showText+'</span>');
$('.revealBoxContents').show();
$('a.collapseLink').click(function() {
// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;
// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
// toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
//$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
$(this).parent().next('.revealBoxContents').slideToggle('slow');
// return false so any link destination is not followed
return false;
});
// toggle the bottom link
$('.collapseLink').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');    
     $(".collapseLink").html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
    $(this).parent('.item').toggleClass('current');

}); 

$(".revealBoxTop a").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("closed").next().slideToggle("slow");
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

    $('.revealBox a').click(function() {
        $(".revealBox").toggleClass("test");
    });


});
```

and here is the url

http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-local/eqs1.htm

Comment: You can test visibility with `.is(':visible')`.

Comment: You use the `is_visible` variable and change its value. Just use that above property `$(this).is(':visible')` in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay I've taken another stab at it - changed lots with no testing! Please replace your code with the code below and advise. if this does't work it might be a good idea to set up a demo at http://www.jsbin.com or http://www.jsfiddle.net

```
// choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
var showText='Hide Information',
    hideText='Show Information';

$('.collapseLink').append('<span class="dottedBot">'+showText+'</span>');
$('.revealBoxContents').show();

// toggle the bottom link
$('.revealBox .collapseLink').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var $targetContainer = $(this).parents('.revealBox').find('revealBoxContents');
         $targetContainer.stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
         if ($targetContainer.is(:visible) {
             $(this).html(showText);
         else {
             $(this).html(hideText);
         }
         // this line below doesn't do anything - can't find an element .item
         $(this).parent('.item').toggleClass('current');
}); 

$('.revealBox a').click(function() {
    // ONLY TARGET PARENT REVEAL BOX
    $(this).parents(".revealBox").toggleClass("test");
});
```

Hopefully we are getting closer!

**EDIT 3**

Went ahead and made a mock-up using your example html:
<strike>http://jsbin.com/iceyi3/edit</strike>
**edit:** *modified version: http://jsbin.com/iceyi3/2/edit*

I found a number of careless errors in my code from above - so I apologise for that! The duplication of 'hide text'/'show text' is because in some areas these are present within html as well as being added by the javascript.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work as it doesnt effect the div .revealBox, also it does something odd with the text change as I need to leave the bottom link independant

Comment: edited the above with some ideas. Please advise on what you mean by "I need to leave the bottom link independant"

Comment: Yeah the link at the bottom changes the flow of the accordion when you click it, if you click it it will chage the text at the top to say the show information when the box is already open

Comment: sorry, bit confused. Have you looked at the jsbin example above (in answer under edit 3). What I've done there is made it so clicking the hide/show link at the bottom of an area triggers a click event on the hide/show link at the top of the area. Therefore there is no difference to how the accordion functions. Additionally when the accordion closes you can't see the hide/show link at the bottom any more. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you!!

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, its almost there but if you look at the js bin and click on the bottom link first the top link still says hide information when the info is already hidden and then when you click the top hide information link afterwards when it expands the bottom link says show information when the information is already showing. I would like to know how to keep the logic of the text when either is clicked. Thanks

Comment: p.s I really apreciate your help

Comment: No worries :) - I see what you mean now. Here is a modified version: http://jsbin.com/iceyi3/2/edit - was limiting my targeting to the clicked element instead of the overall container!

Comment: lnrbob, I would love to buy you a beer, you've been such a great help. Taking the time to help me out, I really apreciate it.

Comment: Thankyou, and if your ever in London. Give us a shout and i'll get that beer for you